# Enterprise geodatabase connection feature geometry invisible in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a database connection made to my PostgreSQL enterprise geodatabase through ArcGIS Pro. I can not see the geometry of the layer through ArcGIS Pro.

I am connected to the database as a user other than `sde`, and trying to see features of a feature class under that corresponding user's schema.

**When I add the layer to the map:**

1. I can "zoom to" the feature and the map zooms to it
2. I can "flash" and it shows its centroid on the screen
3. I can see all the attributes
4. I cannot see any feature geometry through the map. It appears invisible.

**Interesting Notes:**

- When I export the FC from the EGDB to a local FGDB the feature is visible
- When I have an active edit session on the direct EGDB connection layer through ArcGIS Pro the feature DOES become visible.

Anyone know what's going on here?

*ArcGIS Pro 3.0 and Postgres 13.x, ST_Geometry spatial type, Shape polygon. It was originally inserted into the feature class via SQL of inserting a WKT representation into Esri's shape field.*

Invisible egdb layer
[image]

Becomes visible in an edit mode
[image]

Is visible if exported as local feature class
[image]

Comment: How are you assigning the rowid column via SQL?  Is the table versioned? Is there a spatial index on the geometry column? It seems like it may be a query issue.

Comment: @Vince I am incrementing (Esri's) ObjectID by one for each insert. There is a sequence created in the schema which works on this objectid so that features created via queries meet the no-null constraint. The table is not versioned. There is a spatial index on the feature class. What do you mean by "rowid"?

Comment: @Vince Recalculating or delete/create spatial index did nothing. If i exported local and re-imported, the geometry appears. Under "Data Source>Storage" in the FC's properties the invisible layer lists "High Precision using ST_Geometry spatial type (SRID 0)" while the visible layer lists "High Precision using ST_Geometry spatial type (SRID 4326)", though both have Spatial Reference listed in properties of WGS84 with identical Domain/Resolution/Tolerance/etc. During my query insert I do not specify a SRID because I believe it defaults to 4326. This could potentially be the problem. Thoughts?

Comment: No, it doesn't default. ALWAYS specify an SRID.